# How to I make my post title link to a custom field

Tags: custom-field, title

I have a custom field in my posts called `post_bookmark_url` which contains a link. I want the post title that is displayed in the excerpts on my home page to link to the `post_bookmark_url` rather than the permalink of the post. (I am doing this to create a Drudge Report type of aggregator.)

How can I make the "post title" in the excerpts on the home page link to a custom field?

Comment: the_excerpt() only grabs the content portion of the page and has nothing to do with the permalink, which should make this a template issue.

Just find the instance of the_title() being hooked or directly scripted into the post format and replace it with your custom field.

Comment: See also [Change post permalink to external URL from custom field](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/64285/change-post-permalink-to-external-url-from-custom-field)

Comment: Please post the actual Post Title code that you want to modify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that the post title markup looks something like so:

```
<h1><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h1>
```

You merely need to replace `<?php the_permalink(); ?>` with your post custom meta value:

```
<?php $post_bookmark = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'post_bookmark_url', true ); ?>

<h1><a href="<?php echo $post_bookarmk; ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h1>
```

Other caveats:

- You'll want to consider the *context* in which you use this code. If you only need it in your **Blog Posts Index**, then create a `home.php` template file, and put it there. That way, your post titles are not impacted in other contexts.
- You'll probably want to use some fallback in case `post_bookmark_url` isn't set.

Answer (score 1):

You can filter the permalink URL. In this filter, we can check to see if *post_bookmark_url* meta key exists. If it does, we'll use that instead

```
add_filter('post_link','check_for_custom_url',10,3);
function check_for_custom_url( $permalink, $post, $leavename ) {
        $custom = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'post_bookmark_url', true );
        return ( $custom ) ? esc_url( $custom ) : $permalink;
}

//Version to check if we're on the home page as well
add_filter('post_link','check_for_custom_url',10,3);
function check_for_custom_url( $permalink, $post, $leavename ) {
    $custom = false;

    if( is_home() || is_front_page() )
        $custom = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'post_bookmark_url', true );

    return ( $custom ) ? esc_url( $custom ) : $permalink;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. This solution, like the External Permalink plugin, causes ALL the links to the posts to be changed to the link in the custom field. I am looking for a solution that only changes the link that is in the title of the post on the home page. For example, I still want the Recent Posts widget to link to the posts and I still want to be able to Tweet the url of the posts.

Comment: Just updated this to include a check for is_home when filtering.